# Google Sheets graph jump by 1 on the horizontal axis

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-charts, google-data-studio-charts

[image]

How can I change the graph’s horizontal axis to show a jump by 1 instead of 2?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have the values commencing from "one" in the "periode" column,

- Edit the chart
- Select "Customize"
- Select "Horizontal axis"
- Check the option "Treat labels as text"